# jquery, issue with slideToggle when the mouse is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a div .frame, when the mouse is over it I slideToggle a div .content, and when the mouse is leaving .frame I slideToggle again .content again.
It's working well but I have 2 issues:
when the mouse is entering and leaving .frame really fast it's messing the effect, then I don't know why .frame and .content are not aligned.

My css:

```
.frame{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:10%;
     position:relative;
}

.content { 
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px 1px 0px 1px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

my html:

```
    <br><br>

<div class="frame">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="inside">bla bla bla bla bla<br />bla bla bla bla bla<br />bla bla bla bla bla<br />bla bla bla bla bla<br /></div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.frame', function() { 
        var el = $(this);
        content = $(".content");
        content.css({"bottom":el.height(),"width":el.width()});
        content.html('ok ok ok ok');
        el.css("border-top-color","#FFFFFF");
        content.slideToggle(300);   
    }).on('mouseleave','.frame', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        content = $(".content");
        content.stop().slideToggle(300, function(){
            content.html('');
        el.css("border-top-color","#000000");
    });
});
```

here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/Uj2yh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem use - pass `true, true` as params to `slideToggle`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.frame', function() { 
    var el = $(this);
    content = $(".content");
    content.css({"bottom":el.height(),"width":el.width()});
    content.html('ok ok ok ok');
    el.css("border-top-color","#FFFFFF");
    content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);  
}).on('mouseleave','.frame', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    content = $(".content");
    content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300, function(){
        content.html('');
        el.css("border-top-color","#000000");
    });
});
```

For the alignment problem - the problem is the border is for `frame` element and the `content` is inside the frame, so the frames border will come outside `content`s border. Here the fix I used is to move the `content` to `-px` left

```
.content { 
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px 1px 0px 1px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left: -1px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uBUKK/)